# Finding a match inside an object of an array field, using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this schema:

```
var eventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    tags: [{
        tagId: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        name: String,
        description: String
    }],
});

var Event = mongoose.model('Event', eventSchema);
```

And a array of tags ids, eg:

```
var arrayOfTagsIds = [23, 55, 71];
 // in this example I'm not using real mongo id's, which are strings
```

How can I use mongoose's find to search Events that have **any** of these tags?

For example, this event should be in the results because it has tagId 23 and tagId 55:

```
{
   _id: ...,
   name: 'Football tournament',
   tags: [{ tagId: 23, name: 'football', description: '' },
         { tagId: 55, name: 'tournament', description: '' }]
}
```

How must be the query inside find function?

I was thinking of using: `tags.tagId: {$in: arrayOfTagsIds}` but I don't think that is going to work (it doesn't sound okay to use `tags.tagId`, because `tags` is an array)

```
Event
.find({tags.tagId: {$in: arrayOfTagsIds}})
.exec(function (err, events) { ... }
```

Also, doing this kind of query is too slow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use dot notation in keys for both embedded sub-documents and arrays.  However, you do need to quote your key because it contains a dot:

```
Event
.find({'tags.tagId': {$in: arrayOfTagsIds}})
.exec(function (err, events) { ... }
```

To speed up this query you could create an index on `'tags.tagId'`.

Comment: if "tagId" is of "type Schema.Types.ObjectId", the index isn't automatically created?

Comment: No.  The only index that's automatically created is the one on `_id`.